# CubeRealm OpenGL rotation problems, need help. :\

Tags: opengl, camera, c, rotation

I'm totally new to OpenGL and I'm working on a Sandbox game called CubeRealm. My problem you see is rotation. I've got it in my head that to rotate the 'camera' I just rotate all the scene by the negative value of the camera's rotational values. However so far it seems to not be working.

Here's the code snippets:

```
glPushMatrix();

lighting();
/*
 (640^2)/(64^2)=amount of cubes on one 640x640 plane(409,600,4,096)
 */
//TODO: fix z axis problem for translating
glRotatef(-player.camera.rotation.x,1.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(-player.camera.rotation.y,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glRotatef(-player.camera.rotation.z,0.0,0.0,1.0);
renderGrid();

glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();

//SNIPPET2...

case LOOK_UP:
    if(player.camera.rotation.y!=-90.0){ //if they are not looking up
        //make them look up
        player.camera.rotation.y-=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }
    break;
case ROTATE_LEFT:
    if(player.camera.rotation.x!=0.0){
        player.camera.rotation.x-=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }else{
        player.camera.rotation.x=360.0;
        player.camera.rotation.x-=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }
    break;
case LOOK_DOWN:
    if(player.camera.rotation.y!=90.0){ //if they are not looking down
        //make them look down
        player.camera.rotation.y+=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }
    break;
case ROTATE_RIGHT:
    if(player.camera.rotation.x!=360.0){
        player.camera.rotation.x+=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }else{
        player.camera.rotation.x=0;
        player.camera.rotation.x+=90.0;
        //TODO: set direction the camera is facing in
    }
    break;
```

When I press the right arrow key(rotate to the right) it doesn't rotate also when I rotate up(up arrow) it goes weird instead of allowing me to see the top of the skybox it still shows me my test cubes.

So guys how do I fix the rotation, what am I doing wrong?

Note the 'TODO: set direction' stuff is for my local axis system. Those TODOs are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @DeadIMG have done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOOK_UP and LOOK_DOWN must rotate around the x-axis, not around the y-axis.

ROTATE_RIGHT and ROTATE_LEFT must rotate around the y-axis, not around the x-axis.

Immediately rotating around 90 degrees or initializing your angles with 90 degrees will bring your system into a [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) state, resulting in weird rotations. You might want to use smaller angles and step-sizes for starters, particulary not 90 degrees or multiples of it.

Initialize all angles with 0 and start from there:

```
    // init your angles at startup, i.e. main or camera constructor
    player.camera.rotation.x = 0.0;
    player.camera.rotation.y = 0.0;
    player.camera.rotation.z = 0.0;

    // change the step-size and rotation-axis like this:
    case LOOK_UP:
        player.camera.rotation.x+=5.0;
        break;
    case ROTATE_LEFT:
        player.camera.rotation.y-=5.0;
        break;
    case LOOK_DOWN:
        player.camera.rotation.x-=5.0;
        break;
    case ROTATE_RIGHT:
        player.camera.rotation.y+=5.0;
        break;
```

---

Edit: After reviewing your code, here is the list of the bugs, the most important ones are 3), that messed up all the rendering, and 4) the correction for the camera rotation code

1. Off by one error in void setupGrid(), change "<=" to "<" in the while

   ```
   while(_i<GRID_SIZE){
   ```
2. set the initial camera position to {0, 0, 5} in Initialize(), otherwise you wont see the boxes:

   ```
   player.camera.position.x=0;
   player.camera.position.y=0;
   player.camera.position.z=5;
   player.camera.rotation.x=0;
   player.camera.rotation.y=0;
   player.camera.rotation.z=0;
   ```
3. in Reshape change 3rd param of gluPerspective to 1.0

   ```
   gluPerspective(45.0,(double)screenWidth/(double)screenHeight,1.0,CUBE_UNIT*100.0);
   ```
4. Finally the correction of the camera rotation code in Keyboard2() like already written above

   ```
       void Keyboard2(int key,int x,int y){
           switch(key){
               case GLUT_KEY_F1:
                   if(!wireframe){
                       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
                       wireframe=TRUE;
                   }else{
                       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
                       wireframe=FALSE;
                   }
                   break;
               case LOOK_UP:
                   player.camera.rotation.x+=5.0;
                   break;
               case ROTATE_LEFT:
                   player.camera.rotation.y+=5.0;
                   break;
               case LOOK_DOWN:
                   player.camera.rotation.x-=5.0;
                   break;
               case ROTATE_RIGHT:
                   player.camera.rotation.y-=5.0;
                   break;
           };
           return;
       }
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but that creates an even more retarded result. The shapes seem be resized. One this that stands out about your suggestion is that you use x where y should be used and vice versa, why? Would you mind if I uploaded the full code to PasteBin so you could help me with it? Thanks. ;)

Comment: Sure, the more code you show the easier we find the problem. When you want to rotate left/right you must rotate around the y axis, the one that goes upwards. What makes you think you should rotate around the x axis when rotating left/right?

Comment: X is on the left and right, Y is up and down. I'm confused. :\

Comment: Here's my GitHub repo for it: https://github.com/MarcAlexanderReed/CubeRealm

Comment: @VoidElite does [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flight_dynamics_with_text.png) make it clearer for you? Imagine the airplane wants to turn right/left. Then it has to rotate around the yellow array, the y-axis, can you follow here?

Comment: Yes, thankyou. Have you seen the code on my Git? Note: I shall correct the code on my repo with the x and y thing. Tomorow when I have access to my comp. On phone I am.

Comment: @VoidElite it actually works with the code in my answer, the problem is the rest of the code is a mess and has a bunch of bugs. I'm gonna put my edits into my answer in a sec. My advice to you is: As a beginner in OpenGL don't start with a full blown app, start small, draw a triangle, add a camera, make it step by step. There just has to be 1 wrong parameter anywhere and the whole programm doesn't work anymore, i.e. you have a wrong parameter in gluPerspective. Gimme a sec for the edit

Comment: Why thankyou. As I currently am not in a state were I can recompile it with you fixes I am pressuming you are killer sure it works or that you've compiled it yourself. Thanks its just I always aim big, I just like seeing a end goal. I've done the same pretty much with every other API/lib/lang I've ever learnt. :P

Comment: @VoidElite of course I did compile and run it. If that was a thank you, you made it sound, ehm weird.. well, then, you're welcome .. I guess

Comment: Yes it was a thank you. ;) Are you on Mac or did you remake the Makefile/write your own?

Comment: @VoidElite ok :) I tested it on win vc, setting up a glut project with one source file is pretty fast. you don't need a big makefile for 1 source file anyway, with gcc its just 1 command in a shell to compile and link

Comment: Suppose so. ;) Do you have Skype? :)

Comment: Still problems with the solution?

Comment: Well it rotates the cube but I've just discovered that what I need to do is create the illusion of rotating the camera by rotating the  scene(all objects) by the negative value of the camera's rotational values at the camera's position. Also I just think you'd be a cool guy to add to my list on Skype pals. ;)

Comment: thats what you already do in the code above, actually the camera never moves, all that moves is the world and all objects in it, relatively to the camera

Comment: But in CR I've programmed it to rotate the scene on the spot as such whereas I want it to rotate them around the camera's position is there like a rotateAroundf() or summet like that?

Comment: no, you must first translate to the point you want to rotate around, then call glRotate. You might want to close this question as it is answered, the system is not made for long discussions. Why not just ask new questions, its for free after all.

Comment: Ok but first, could I add you on Skype?? :3

Comment: @MaikSemder let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/744/discussion-between-voidelite-and-maik-semder)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't simply add and subtract values from rotation. These values need to be calculated using math formulas using trigonometry. I was designing a project a while back and needed a camera to move in 3d space. Check out this project and the camera class from it. It will do precisely what you need granted you want to move freely in 3d space with minimal code.

http://www.paulsprojects.net/opengl/q3bsp/q3bsp.html

Edit: Here is another more straightforward example with the math involved as well:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=Quaternion_Camera_Class

Nehe's OpenGL tutorials are a fantastic reference for beginners but if you are going to go much further, grab an OpenGL book with current standards/practices.

Comment: That's wrong, you can simply add values to each component of Euler Angles. Euler Angles suffer from Gimbal Lock, but that is because each rotation around the axes is appliad one after another, but you can of course simply add/subtract values for each component. -1